# How to filter two columns with one TextBox - Filter in two columns in DataGridView slow down performance- Visual Basic

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have 2 columns in a Datagridview:

1. English words
2. Arabic meanings

I want to search for both English and Arabic with only one TextBox I used this but it slows performance:

```
Me.TbBindingSource.Filter = "English like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%' Or Arabic like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
```

My new approach was to check one the text for any arabic characters. If there are any, the query will only search the arabic meanings column. Otherwise it will search for the english words:

```
Dim x As Char = "و"
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains(x) Then
        TbBindingSource.Filter = "Arabic like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
    Else
        TbBindingSource.Filter = "English like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
    End If
```

I only know how to check for a single arabic character, but I need to check for them all.

PS: I'm new at Visual Basic and understand a bit of C#, so if you could give me a hint in either of those, that would be great.

Comment: Why did you tag this as c#?

Comment: You should take care when using concatenated strings as database queries. The keyword here is SQL injection. It can be used to execute malicious code on your database just by typing into your textbox.

Comment: Because I now a little bit about c# and if have a c# code for my problem I convert it to visual basic

Comment: You cannot precisely detect the language from the entered text, for example, what would be the language if user enter something like `و this`?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to give the user a drop-down to select the language for the filter. Otherwise you could use your initial approach and check for any arabic character: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48facc69-9506-4146-b1b9-e1f3ef4e0ce7/how-do-i-check-whether-my-string-contains-arabic-characters-or-not?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I like the idea of the user selecting the language but I'd probably go with radio buttons rather than a drop-down, given that it's just two choices.

Comment: Just Instead of `Dim x As Char = "و"` I want to use `Dim x As Char = {"و" ,"ك" ,"د" ,"ج", ...}`  and x as variable refers to all Arabic characters to use it in IF statement.

Comment: If I'm not able to do this I will use drop-down to select or radio buttons or just two  buttons.

Answer (score 0):

"LIKE" is a powerful keyword, but it slows down SQL a lot. You should narrow your search as much as possible before using it.

Your problem seems to be the kind of problem which sounds simple enough, but is more like a small pile of problems which can become complex quickly.

Still, here's some code that will help you to guess if a word is written in arabic or in english. Hope it helps:

```
Public Function IsThisArabic(ByVal word As String) As Boolean
    For Each car As Char In word.ToCharArray
        If AscW(car) > 600 Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

If you feel that less characters would be enough, suits yourself. This function look at every character of the word and returns True if there's at least one arabic ascii char (and then stop looking).

Next know your target audience: do you have a short or a vast dictionary? Will you often check the same words or always new words?

If you have only a short dictionnary, you may want to just grab all of it instead of doing many queries, and work from your own memory. If you have reasons to think that you will look for the same words more than once, you should build cache.